# Javascript to Jquery for loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to convert these `for` loops into jQuery but I am unsure how to do this. I am also unsure of how to convert `document.querySelector`. I tried to convert it like this:

```
$('.table1 tbody')
```

but it does not work when you call

```
tablebody.row[]
```

This is my code:

```
var headertext = [],
    headers = $(".table1 th"),
    tablebody = document.querySelector(".table1 tbody");

for(var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    var current = headers[i];
    headertext.push(current.textContent.replace(/\r?\n|\r/,""));
}
for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
    for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
        col.setAttribute("data-th", headertext[j]);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: take a look at: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/iterating/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map()` to create an array from the attributes of the specified `th` elements. You can then loop through that array and set the `data` attribute on the required `td` elements.

That being said, you can change the logic entirely to do this in a single `each()` loop. Try this:

```
var $headers = $('.table1 th');
$('tr > td').each(function(i) {
    $(this).data('th', $headers.eq($(this).index()).text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/, ""));
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/LnbLk1y1/)

Note that jQuery keeps `data` attributes in an internal cache, so you won't see any changes to the DOM with the above code (which is why in the jsFiddle example I set the `text()` too). This is absolutely fine, you just need to remember to use jQuery's getter signature of `data()` to retrieve the attribute.

For your reference, your attempt to convert `querySelector` to `$('.table1 tbody')` didn't work because the jQuery version returns a jQuery object, not a DOMElement, and jQuery object's don't have `rows` property.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `each` function in jquery to iterate over elements.

```
$('.table1 th').each(function(index){
      var text=$(this).text();
});
```

And

```
$('.table1 tbody td').each(function(index){
      var tdObject=$(this);
      // loop for iterating over all the TDs of table.
      // You can use tdObject to get text, class and other values.
      // e.g. var id = tdObject.attr('id');
      var text=tdObject.text();
});
```